# How to retrieve text from a select input option with java spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, http, spring-mvc

I have a JSP with a select input in a form, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="/confirm">
  <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="1">1st choice</option>
    <option value="2">2nd choice</option>
    <option value="3">3rd choice</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I have a spring controller that handles this form as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView confirm(@RequestParam int dropdown,
                            HttpServletRequest request,
                            Model model)
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("selection", dropdown);
    modelAndView.setViewName("confirm");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

On my confirm view, if I want to display the value of the dropdown selection then I can do that like this:

```
<div id="dropselection">${selection}</div>
```

If the user selected the first option, "1st choice", for example, then the value that would be passed to the confirm page would be `1`.

However, what if I want to pass along the text value from the select tag option? What if a user selected the first option and I needed the value `1st choice` to be passed into the controller? How would I retrieve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218693/how-to-pass-data-from-formselect-spring-mvc can help u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't retrieve that value. In form submission it only pass value attribute of select, input tags.

Two options available

1. You can change value field text to description

**If you have hard code that just change that to**

```
<option value="3rd choice">3rd choice</option>
```

**If you have dynamic code, then you can use this kind of approach**

```
List<Answer> answerList = new ArrayList<Answer>();
Answer answer = new Answer();
answer.setAnswerId(3);
answer.setDescription(3rd choice);
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();     
modelAndView.addObject("answerList", answerList);   

<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <c:forEach items="${answerList}" var="answer" varStatus="answerStatus">
        <option value="${answer.description}" label="${answer.description}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

or keep options as it is and in controller level you can get that value from dropdown request parameter (example: 3)

And after that you can loop the answer list (answerList) and find value in controller level.

```
<c:forEach items="${answerList}" var="answer" varStatus="answerStatus">
    <option value="${answer.answerId}" label="${answer.description}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Note

```
answer.answerId = 3
answer.description = 3rd choice
```