# Is there any way to dispatch data from a table of mysql to the drop-down of a JSP page?

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I don't want to use scriptlets inside jsp page to do this, is there any way through which I can actually dispatch values inside drop-down?

Comment: why not call a bean to populate drop down?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218693/how-to-pass-data-from-formselect-spring-mvc check this link